# Cassandra CPU performance

Tags: cassandra

I deployed a Cassandra 2.2 ring composed by 4 nodes in the cloud with 8 vCPU and 8GB of ram. I am running some tests now with cassandra-stress and YCSB tools to test its performance. I am mainly interested in read requests with a small amount of write requests (95%/5%).

Running the experiments, I noticed that even setting a high number of threads (or clients) the CPU (and disk) does not saturate, but still always around the 60% of utilisation.

I am trying to figure out where is the bottleneck in my system. From the hardware point of view it seems all ok to me.
[dstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaGFz.png)

I also looked into the Cassandra configuration file to see if there are some tuning parameters to increase the system throughput. I increase the value of  concurrent_read/write parameter, but it doesn't increase the performance.
The log file also does not contain any warning.

What it could be that is limiting my system?
Thanks

Comment: The main thing that bottlenecks a Cassandra node, is a poor data model and ill-designed queries that rely on secondary indexes or BATCH statements.  It'd help to see what (exactly) you are running on your nodes.  You should also check `nodetool compactionstats` to see if you are constantly compacting (another sign of a poor data model or use case).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider running cassandra-stress from outside the cluster and on multiple instances as described in
[Usage of the Cassandra tool cassandra-stress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336753/usage-of-the-cassandra-tool-cassandra-stress)